# bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:strip_unused compilation failure

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to run this bazel command from within my docker image

```
docker run -it  gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
cd /tensorflow
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:strip_unused
```

However it fails with this error:

```
ERROR: /tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:1970:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/core/kernels:svd_op' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG ... (remaining 107 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 4.
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Target //tensorflow/python/tools:strip_unused failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 609.363s, Critical Path: 456.46s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error occurs when gcc is killed by the operating system. Do you have enough ram/swap?

I don't think this is Bazel or Tensorflow specific.

Comment: Yes that was correct. I solved it by running ```bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:strip_unused  --local_resources 2048,.5,1.0```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you ran out of RAM. Please post the output of `dmesg | tail` right after the build fails.